# Facebook Secure Canvas URL Requirement and Legacy Applications

Tags: facebook, ssl

With Facebook requiring a secure URL for Canvas applications on October 1st, what will happen to legacy applications that have no URL specified for the Secure Canvas URL?  Will they continue to load over HTTP and fail over HTTPS?

Suppose an application has URLs specified for the Canvas, Page Tab, and Secure Page Tab, but no URL specified for the Secure Canvas.. will these applications continue to function, or will they be blocked entirely because they lack a secure URL for the Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the applications without secure connection (https) are still working. Today is October 05 and I'm not seeing any sort of change in my apps. They are working nicely and people have access.

Comment: I just confirmed this yesterday (12 Oct 2011).  The updates to the Facebook API allowed us finish populating the secure canvas url.

Answer (score 5):

use simple bit.ly address in your canvas url.... it works

Comment: Not really, you need to add a trailing slash to the URL (FB requires it) and bitly doesn't like it

Comment: Found the solution, just add a question mark in the end of the URL, somehow Facebook also likes that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any longer.. "There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

Answer (score 1):

ye unfortunately the entire app will be blocked, well that's what im reading around the web anyways. 
AFAIK you need your secure URL to have some location URL for it to function.

And now i see Facebook has added a message for users to enable secure browsing when u login. so even more so no to get a secure link than ever.

If you are struggling try out http://social-server.com. Instead of buying a SSL certificate it does the same thing for free and its instant!

Answer (score 1):

Applications will enter a new 'disabled' mode, similar to sandbox, until Secure Callback URL is set.

Answer (score 0):

Come October 1st as the dev pages states on facebook you will be required to have a secure url. I just picked up a cheap SSL cert from godaddy for like 16 bucks for a year. i do not know if they still have the deal going on, but it definitively worth checking. Once the cert is installed on your server, you do not need to migrate anything, the whole process took like 2 hours most of which was waiting on godaddy.

Comment: We have several Facebook applications that it will be cumbersome to populate the Secure Canvas URL (no method in the Facebook API to populate this).  We have the cert installed.. I'm curious about the Secure Canvas URL field and the behavior of those apps that have no URL specified.

Answer (score 0):

Just researching this issue; I don't have an ssl cert and when I try to access my app as a Facebook app I get:

[image]

I think no ssl is the cause so looks like i need to buy one :(

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an interesting hack for this problem.

You can create a HTML file that is accessible over HTTPS that just redirects to your webpage. For example, you can use dropbox. Since Facebook loads your secure canvas URL page in an iframe, your code needs to redirect the top page. Something like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function onLoad() {
      window.top.location.href=’<your website>’;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload=”onLoad()”>
    <p>Please wait while you are being redirected to <your website name>…</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And provide this link as the secure canvas URL. I blogged about this in more detail - http://blog.almabase.com/post/84579042935/interesting-hack-for-facebook-secure-canvas-url